# Typecasting custom structs

Tags: c++, struct, casting

I have two structs defining a point and a vector in a given frame.

```
struct point3D
{
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
};
struct vector3D
{
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
};
```

The reason they are defined as two different structs is because there are other functions that treat a point(`point3D`) differently to a vector (`vector3D`) tho they have the same type of member variables

I was wondering if there is a way to typecast one of them into another say for example:

```
point3D variable1;
vector3D variable2;
variable2=(vector3D)variable1;
```

Comment: You can define a conversion operator: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Comment: Perhaps it would make more sense to do something like `point - origin` or `point.as_vector_from_origin()` instead of a direct cast.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that, if they represent fundamentally different things?

Comment: maybe you could derive `point3D` from `vector3D`, as a point is a position vector

Comment: are you using OpenCV?

Comment: @codekaizer I am not using OpenCV

Comment: I actually like to think like an assembler programmer and treat C and C++ as portable assemblers. Sometimes it is just nice to disable aliasing optimizations and just brute force cast one struct ptr to a compatible pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this

```
struct vector3D
{
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
};

struct point3D
{
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
  explicit operator vector3D() {
    return {x, y, z};
  }
};
```

Comment: Why `explicit`? (just for my edification). Thx.

Comment: @PaulSanders the explicit is because the example gave by OP doesn't require implicit casting and implicit casting is to be avoided

Comment: OK, but _maybe_ his example should have been `variable2 = variable1;`

Comment: @PaulSanders maybe it should have but then i wouldn't have added the explicit

Comment: @PaulSanders, If the whole point of having two separate classes is to make sure you don't mix and match the two's semantics, implicitly converting between them kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: @chris Yes, but then I did say above _Why would you ever want to do that?_ - and never got a response.  The question is rather confused IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you the knife, even though I am sure you are not a surgean. Karsten recommended - in a comment - to derive point from vector. If that is not fine, go ahead and cheat: the proper casting operator is `reinterpret_cast`.

```
point3D variable1; 
vector3D variable2;
variable2=reinterpret_cast<vector3D&>(variable1);
```

but that was C++. If a C style cast is what you need, then a pointer cast is the way:

```
variable2=*(vector3D*)(void*)&variable1;
```

Either of the two solutions above are discouraged. A redesign I would consider, if in your shoes I were.

Comment: You cannot do that in C, it violates the *Strict Aliasing Rule*, see [C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6,7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Irrelevant. casting between any two object pointers has always been valid C code. The void pointer casting in the snippet is an overkill that I used.

Comment: Not to quarrel, but in C when you are attempting to access an object of type `point3D` through a pointer of `vector3D` (which is not `char`), then that is a violation of the strict aliasing rule.  *"The effective type of an object for an access to its stored value is the declared type of the object..."*. Now you can argue that each is a *type compatible with the effective type*, but the C example above is simply type-punning `point3D` to `vector3D`. The proper way to do that would be a `union` between the types.

Comment: agreed. its one reason not to use it. but type punning is widely used, even in standard api(eg sockaddr_in,...). and no difference between casting and union: type punning to/from anything but char/void is not guaranteed, although handled correctly on common cases. in the absence of alaising (sample code does not store pointer, just reads the pointee), no practical problems. but the term 'cheating' in the answer hints about subtlities and hazards around type punning.

Comment: @Red.Wave: Recognition of situations where an lvalue or pointer of one type is derived from a pointer or lvalue of another is a Quality of Implementation issue, and the Standard makes no attempt to require that compilers be of sufficient quality to be suitable for any particular purpose.  On the other hand, I don't think the authors of the Standard expected quality compilers to interpret the term "aliasing" in the footnote to 6.5p7 to include cases where pointers and lvalues are derived and used in strictly nested fashion, because no decent compiler should have any problem with such cases.